# How to not delete the inside of .TXT file after re-lauching program

Tags: c

I have been learning C for 1 week and from the knowledge i have learned untill now i decided to make program which will store the information about a person in .TXT file ( like number , surname, last name etc..) but to be able to enter any information u have to first create a password( or even more than 1) and then log in. All those passwords are saved to PASSWORDS.TXT and when u want to log in and enter password it scans the file and compare passwords and if the entered password is there then you can continue otherwise it will close the program.

**Now here's the problem i'm facing :**

After i re-launch the program every password from the previous one got deleted(they were re-written) , the same happens with names and all those informations which have been entered in the program. Is there any function / or a way how to store all of them even after re-launching ? Sorry for my bad english and explanation skills it is not my native language and i have tried to search it on google but i could not understand it or was no the case i was looking for.

**An Example :**

PASSSORDS.TXT 1st time:

123456 342478 asdds45789 145vwrf

After closing the program and re-launching again and then creating new passwords for example new123 asd456 the inside of PASSWORDS.TXT looks like

PASSWORDS.TXT 2nd time:

new123 asd456

I'll be very thankful for any given guide.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void emptyBuffer() {
    char c = 'a';
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    c = getchar();
}

return;
}

int main()
{
FILE *fw, //na zapis
     *fr; //na citanie
char heslo[256],heslo2[256];
int c,p,i,dlzka,index,j,cislo,konec = 0,pocet = 0; //pocitadla
char buffer[1024],string[10];

 printf("Toto je program na vytvorenie pristupoveho hesla\n\n");
fw = fopen("C:/Users/Marek/Desktop/HESLA.TXT","w"); 

do {
printf("Enter your password: ");
scanf("%s",&heslo);
emptyBuffer();
fprintf(fw,"%s ",heslo);
printf("Do you want to create another password?A/N");
c = getchar();
} while (( c == 'a') || ( c == 'A'));

fclose(fw);
printf("Now you can log in with your created passwords\n\n");
fr = fopen("C:/Users/Marek/Desktop/HESLA.TXT","r");
printf("Zadaj prihlasovacie heslo: ");
scanf("%s",&heslo2);
dlzka = strlen(heslo2);

while ((c = fgetc(fr)) != EOF)
    pocet++;

fclose(fr);
fr = fopen("C:/Users/Marek/Desktop/HESLA.TXT","r");


while (fscanf(fr, " %1023[^\n]", buffer) != EOF)
{
}

for (i = 0; i <= pocet; i++){
            if (heslo2[0] == buffer[i]){
                index = i+1;
                p = 1;
                for (j = 1;j < dlzka; j++ ){
                    if (heslo2[j] == buffer[index]) {
                        index++;
                        p++;
                    }
                    else
                        break;

                }
            if (p == dlzka && buffer[index] == ' ')
                konec = 1;
            else
                konec = 0;
            }
}

fclose(fr);

if (konec == 1){

    if ((fw = fopen("C:/Users/Marek/Desktop/UDAJE.TXT", "w")) == NULL) {  //      test suboru 
    printf("Subor UDAJE.TXT sa nepodarilo otvorit\n");
    return 1;
    }

    printf("\nYou were sucsesfully loged in\n");
    printf("Here you can enter datas\n");

    int index1 = 0;

    do {
        index1++;
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", &string);
        fprintf(fw, "%d\n%s\n",index1, string);
        printf("Enter your number: ");
        scanf("%d",&cislo);
        fprintf(fw, "%d\n",cislo);
        printf("If u wanna add more datas press a/A otherwise press N: ");
        emptyBuffer();
        c = getchar();
    } while (( c == 'a') || ( c == 'A'));

 if (fclose(fw) == EOF)  // test uzavretia suboru
     printf("Subor UDAJE.TXT sa nepodarilo zavret\n");  
}
else
    printf("You have entered an invalid password");






return 0;

}
```

PART of the old code in my language will translate it into english soon.

Comment: You should include some relevant code here (how about the code where you open and write to the password file?), or else people will just guess and this will likely get closed.

Comment: Open the file in `"a"`  or `"a+"`  mode to append instead of write mode, [cf `fopen` docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are opening the file with `fw = fopen("C:/Users/Marek/Desktop/HESLA.TXT","w");`. If the file you are trying to open **already exists** this will **erase the contents** within it and begin writing again from the start of the file. You want to change `"w"` to `"a"`, which will **append to the end** of the file and leave what was previously in the file untouched.

This [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) includes more information and a handy table on file opening modes.

Comment: thank you i'm going to try it it will probably works like you said

Answer (score 0):

You can't really just remove characte4rs from inside a text file. There are basically two techniques that are commonly used:

1. Read all of the file into memory, remove what you want from the memory buffer, close and reopen the file (thereby truncating it) and write the (modified) buffer.
2. Read from the file while writing to a temporary file, removing the data you don't want to save as you go. Then rename the temporary file as the original file.

Method 1 is good for small files, while method 2 is better for larger files.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the following:

1. You open the file in "append" mode - meaning you want to add text. Example:

   passFile = fopen("PASSWORDS.TXT", "a");
   //write the passwords
2. You must not forget to close the file stream correctly! For example:

   fclose(passFile);

Good luck!

Comment: The output file is clearly opened using `"w"` and closed according to the code in the question.

Comment: I answered before he posted the code... :)